# CleanWebpackPlugin not letting me rebuild

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to add CleanWebpackPlugin to my webpack build. When I add in the CleanWebpackPlugin to my list of plugins, it successfully removes my dist/ folder, but my webpack build fails to rebuild the dist folder. If I don't include the CleanWebpackPlugin in my list of plugins and manually remove the dist/ folder, webpack will successfully rebuild the dist/ folder. Why is CleanWebpackPlugin disabling webpack from rebuilding the dist/ folder and how can I fix this? Thanks!

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

let pathsToClean = [
  DIST_DIR
];

let cleanOptions = {
  verbose: true
};

const config = {
  entry: [
    "babel-polyfill",
    SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    SRC_DIR + "/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss",
  ],
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR + "/app/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: "/app/"
  },
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:5001',
        secure: false,
    },
}
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "eslint-loader",
        options: {
          failOnWarning: false,
          failOnError: true
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: SRC_DIR,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'stage-2']
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: 'css-loader?importLoaders=1',
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader']),
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: ['file-loader?context=src/images&name=images/[path][name].[ext]', {
          loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
          query: {
            mozjpeg: {
              progressive: true,
            },
            gifsicle: {
              interlaced: false,
            },
            optipng: {
              optimizationLevel: 7,
            },
            pngquant: {
              quality: '75-90',
              speed: 3,
            },
          },
        }],
        exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
        include: __dirname,
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        // loader: "url?limit=10000"
        use: "url-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: "application.css",
      allChunks: true
    }),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(pathsToClean, cleanOptions),
  ]
};

module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "watch": "webpack --progress --watch",
    "start": "npm run build",
    "build": "webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --history-api-fallback",
    "build:dev": "webpack && cp src/index.html dist/index.html",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p && cp src/index.html dist/index.html"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "7.0.0-beta.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint": "3.x",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^6.0.0-beta.7",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "jest": "^23.1.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^1.6.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch": "^0.5.7",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "cross-fetch": "^1.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.0.4",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^0.4.42",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.19.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "query-string": "^5.0.1",
    "rc-time-picker": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.4",
    "react-circular-progressbar": "^0.8.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.59.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-highcharts": "^15.0.0",
    "react-list": "^0.8.8",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.10",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "styled-components": "3.2.3",
    "twilio-client": "^1.4.33"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./node_modules/jest-enzyme/lib/index.js"
  }
}
```

**stacktrace:**

```
jimmy:bei-bei/ (webpack_enhancements_v1) $ ys                                                                                                                                  [13:06:46]
yarn run v1.6.0
$ npm run build

> bei-bei@1.0.0 build /Users/jemery/dev/bei-bei
> webpack -d && cp src/index.html dist/index.html && webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --history-api-fallback

Hash: 93182bb3b389691fad05
Version: webpack 3.7.1
Time: 22822ms
                                 Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot   166 kB          [emitted]         
  b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf   166 kB          [emitted]         
  912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg   444 kB          [emitted]  [big]  
images/_/app/assets/images/bei-bei.png  2.94 kB          [emitted]         
                             bundle.js  14.3 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
                       application.css   396 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [41] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 509 bytes {0} [built]
 [102] ./src/app/actions/users.js 3.54 kB {0} [built]
 [474] multi babel-polyfill ./src/app/index.js ./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./src/app/components/styles.scss font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css rc-time-picker/assets/index.css react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css @trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css 124 bytes {0} [built]
 [676] ./src/app/index.js 1.67 kB {0} [built]
 [725] ./src/app/reducers/index.js 3.14 kB {0} [built]
 [741] ./src/app/reducers/ui.js 8.18 kB {0} [built]
 [742] ./src/app/reducers/users.js 1.47 kB {0} [built]
 [743] ./src/app/reducers/search.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
 [744] ./src/app/reducers/schools.js 4.35 kB {0} [built]
 [745] ./src/app/reducers/statuses.js 4.55 kB {0} [built]
 [746] ./src/app/reducers/table.js 8.71 kB {0} [built]
 [747] ./src/app/reducers/terms.js 4.49 kB {0} [built]
 [748] ./src/app/reducers/trays.js 17.5 kB {0} [built]
 [749] ./src/app/routes.js 6.49 kB {0} [built]
[1246] ./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 41 bytes {0} [built]
    + 1238 hidden modules

WARNING in ./src/app/actions/prospect.js

/Users/jemery/dev/bei-bei/src/app/actions/prospect.js
  1:8  warning  'constants' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

✖ 1 problem (0 errors, 1 warning)

 @ ./src/app/components/prospect/prospectContainer.js 19:16-49
 @ ./src/app/components/prospects/prospectsRoutes.js
 @ ./src/app/routes.js
 @ ./src/app/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/app/index.js ./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./src/app/components/styles.scss font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css rc-time-picker/assets/index.css react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css @trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css

...

✖ 4 problems (0 errors, 4 warnings)

 @ ./src/app/components/reports/callReportContainer.js 61:22-63
 @ ./src/app/components/reports/reports.js
 @ ./src/app/routes.js
 @ ./src/app/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/app/index.js ./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss ./src/app/components/styles.scss font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css rc-time-picker/assets/index.css react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css @trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js?importLoaders=1!node_modules/react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css:
       2 modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js?importLoaders=1!node_modules/rc-time-picker/assets/index.css:
       2 modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js?importLoaders=1!node_modules/react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css:
       2 modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js?importLoaders=1!node_modules/@trendmicro/react-toggle-switch/dist/react-toggle-switch.css:
       2 modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss:
                                   Asset    Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713.eot  166 kB          [emitted]         
    b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9.ttf  166 kB          [emitted]         
    912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde.svg  444 kB          [emitted]  [big]  
       8 modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!src/app/components/styles.scss:
       2 modules
Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js!node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:
       [0] ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss 101 kB {0} [built]
        + 1 hidden module
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /app/
Content not from webpack is served from ./dist
404s will fallback to /index.html
```

Comment: post the error that you are getting too, the stack trace

Comment: stacktrace added.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can happens because the order is:

1. Build the project
2. Delete 'just built' DIST_DIR.

try to add:

```
let cleanOptions = {
  exclude: ['bundle.js'],
};
```